# Matrix multiplication between two feature maps in Caffe

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, matrix-multiplication

Is there a layer (or a simple combination of layers) which can be used to perform matrix multiplication between two feature maps? For example, say there is a blob is of size MxN and another one of size NxP, is there a layer which can multiply these two blobs like a matrix?

Answer (score 1):

There is a planned change to caffe to allow for manipulations as you ask, that is, treating parameter blobs as regular blobs. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41580924/1714410) for more information.

Until this change is complete, you might consider

1. `"Tile"`ing the blobs into `M`x`N`x`P` blobs.
2. Using `"Eltwise"` layer for element-wise multiplication.
3. Using `"Pooling"` with global pool on the `N` axis.

Comment: I thought of this but it takes much more memory (linearly more). I ended up using, caffe_gpu_gemm as I didn't need backward pass.