# Is there an example .prototxt demonstrating use of "Parameter Layer" in caffe?

Tags: conv-neural-network, caffe, layer

I am trying to understand how to use "Parameter Layer" in caffe https://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers/parameter.html
and how it might be useful in defining the network. Does anyone have an example .prototxt (e.g. MNIST, etc.) of how it can be utilized?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is "Parameter" layer in caffe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41578532/what-is-parameter-layer-in-caffe)

Comment: It is, but I am looking for an actual example with .prototxt that somebody used in their model. If you find any - it will be greatly appreciated!